# No menu option in vlc

Tags: vlc

I do use vlc player for watching movies and I dont have any idea what happened with my vlc I am not getting any icons or anything not even time bar...its just the video, no preferences nothing...I know we can get it by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> , but nothing is happening with that as well.

I am not getting any option when I hover over to title bar and when I right click anywhere on the video. How can I solve this issue?

Note : I even uninstalled and installed it again but still the same problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delete the `~/.config/vlc` folder. You will lose your VLC settings but it's likely to undo whatever you've done to lead to this result. You can remove it by running the following in the terminal:

```
rm -r ~/.config/vlc
```

Comment: but I cant find any .config folder

Comment: It did work...thanks a lot... :) can you tell me where can I exactly find .config folder becoz I did some research online and got same solution but was not able to find .config folder...

Comment: Would have given you 1 up too but dont have that much reputation... :(

Comment: The .config folder is in your home directory. If the name of a file or a folder starts with a `.`, that means it's hidden. In the default Ubuntu filemanager, Nautilus, they can be displayed by hitting Ctrl+H.

Comment: got it thanx a lotz buddy :)