# Menu bar is no more visible in vlc

Tags: vlc, menu-bar

VLC was working fine until this happened: The menu bar is no more visible. I don't remember making any configuration changes, though I have tried to revert them, if any with the help of this question:

- [No menu option in VLC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245709/no-menu-option-in-vlc)

Attaching a screenshot of the problem I am talking about:
[image: vlc error]

The menu bar is visible from all other applications I use regularly. Also, I am able to access the menu options using  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>M/H/A/V</kbd>, but this is very inconvenient.

How do I make it visible again?

**Specifications:**

- Ubuntu 12.10
- VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower

Comment: Please look here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/245709/no-menu-option-in-vlc?rq=1

Comment: I have mentioned about the question you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't find a clean way of resolving this, so did a complete reinstallation of vlc, based on [user2325513](https://askubuntu.com/users/195496/user2325513)'s comment as follows:

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc
```

Searched for files containing "vlc" in their name using

```
find / -name vlc
```

Deleted all configuration files found using this as

```
rm -r ~/.config/vlc
rm -r ~/.cache/vlc
```

Installed vlc using apt

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Found that vlc had its menu bar back!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove VLC's `.cache` and `.config` file, using these commands in a terminal window:

```
rm -r ~/.config/vlc
rm -r ~/.cache/vlc
```

Comment: Had tried these to no avail.